# How to deploy Yii2 Advanced application on a shared Hosting

Tags: git, composer-php, yii2, shared-hosting, yii2-advanced-app

Yii2 advanced application with vendor folder its more than ~100 MB, so its very difficult to upload using FTP software.

1. I need to update composer after uploading my application in a shared server.
2. Unable to clone from git

Comment: If you have added vendor folder within you git repository. Please remove it from git. It is not recommended to add vendor folder within your repository.

Comment: Compress your source code into a zip file, upload this file to your hosting then extract it. Most of shared Hosting support unzip in cpanel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps for deploying yii2 advanced app on a shared hosting
(note : You need to have ssh access to the server, if not: contact your hosting provider)

1. Generating a SSH Key Pair : open terminal and type the following

   **ssh-keygen -t dsa**

   OR

   **ssh-keygen -t rsa**
2. The out put will be similar to

> Generating public/private dsa key pair.  Enter file in which to save
>   the key (~/.ssh/id_dsa): Press [Enter] key  Enter passphrase (empty
>   for no passphrase): Press [Enter] key  Enter same passphrase again:
>   Press [Enter] key  Your identification has been saved in ~/.ssh/id_dsa
>   Your public key has been saved in ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub  The key
>   fingerprint is:

OR

> Generating public/private dsa key pair.  Enter file in which to save
>   the key (~/.ssh/id_dsa): Press [Enter] key  Enter passphrase (empty
>   for no passphrase): Press [Enter] key  Enter same passphrase again:
>   Press [Enter] key  Your identification has been saved in ~/.ssh/id_dsa
>   Your public key has been saved in ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub  The key
>   fingerprint is:

3. Create a directory as .ssh (note the preceding dot) under /home// for your hosting package on the remote host. You will then have to create a file named authorized_keys inside this .ssh directory
4. Copy the content of the local ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub or ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub file into the authorized_keys file
5. For connecting your server, open terminal and enter following

   **ssh -l user remote-server**

Replace *user* with your cpanel username and *remote-server* with your remote server host name. Enter your cpanel password, terminal will login your remote server using ssh.

1. Clone your application from git repository

   **`git clone https://username@gitlab.com/username/repository.git public_html`**
2. Go to public_html do the following

   **curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php**

   **php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.0"**

   **php init**
3. Set environment as Production (recommended)

   **php composer.phar update**

This will download all dependencies and setup your app, don't forget to configure database in main configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem and was without ssh access. I however noticed that the bulk of the size and files was caused by the `.git` folders of my project and the vendors. My solution was to set my FTP client to ignore all files and folders starting with `.git`.

On Filezilla, for example, this can be done by going to View->Filename Filters and editing the `CVS and SVN` filter to ignore '.git*'.

Comment: Why did you ignote git files?? if you are using git regularly, you can deploye whole project from git server, it will not use your local bandwidth and also very fast compare to FTP, yii is also a package so we can download it through `composer.phar`

Comment: No SSH access. Can't use git.

Comment: You just contact your hosting provider,  **bigrock** and **Godaddy** are providing `SSH` access, then you can use `.git` also

Comment: What I meant was sometimes SSH isn't available e.g on a Windows machine.

Comment: Use **[Putty software](http://www.putty.org/)** for `SSH` in windows download with documentation from